# compare next record in the same table sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table having 2 columns trans_date and amount.
I want to a query that give me the amount if the transdate diff of a record and the next record is 1 day or same day.

explanation:

```
AMOUNT    TRANS_DATE

2645    2011-05-11 20:57:27.000
2640    2011-05-12 00:00:00.000
2645    2011-05-15 18:01:11.000
2645    2011-06-15 18:27:45.000
2645    2011-06-16 17:06:33.000
2645    2011-06-18 15:19:19.000
2645    2011-06-23 15:42:18.000
```

the query should show me only

```
 AMOUNT    TRANS_DATE

    2645    2011-05-11 20:57:27.000
    2640    2011-05-12 00:00:00.000
    2645    2011-05-15 18:01:11.000
    2645    2011-06-15 18:27:45.000
    2645    2011-06-16 17:06:33.000
```

all i have tried is

```
select DATEDIFF(DAY,a.TRANS_DATE,b.TRANS_DATE) from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS a inner join ( select * from (select a.*,rank() over (order by id) as ra from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS a, FIN_AP_PAYMENTS b )tbl )



select a.TRANS_DATE,b.TRANS_DATE,rank() over (order by a.id) as ra1,rank() over (order by b.id) as ra2 from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS a,FIN_AP_PAYMENTS b



select DATEDIFF(day,tbl.TRANS_DATE,tbl2.TRANS_DATE) from (select a.*,rank() over (order by id) as ra from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS a) tbl inner join (select a.*,rank() over (order by a.id) as ra1 from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS a ) tbl2 on tbl.id=tbl2.id
```

Comment: i have used rank , row_number.. but nothing is returning the desired result.

Comment: Show us your tried query

Comment: select DATEDIFF(DAY,a.TRANS_DATE,b.TRANS_DATE)  from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS a 
inner join 
(
select * from (select a.*,rank() over (order by id) as ra from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS a,
FIN_AP_PAYMENTS b )tbl )

Comment: select a.TRANS_DATE,b.TRANS_DATE,rank() over (order by a.id) as ra1,rank() over (order by b.id) as ra2 from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS a,FIN_AP_PAYMENTS b

Comment: Put it in the question section , not in comment. It would be really helpful for others

Comment: select DATEDIFF(day,tbl.TRANS_DATE,tbl2.TRANS_DATE) from 
(select a.*,rank() over (order by id) as ra from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS a) tbl
inner join  
(select a.*,rank() over (order by a.id) as ra1 from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS a ) tbl2 
on tbl.id=tbl2.id

Comment: Why is `2645    2011-05-15 18:01:11.000` included in the output?  It's 3 days after the previous record and 31 before the next (June 15th)?  Am I missing something?

Comment: dateDIFF is more than 1 with previous and next record

Comment: But you asked for *transdate diff of a record and the next record is **1 day or same day**.*.  Can you edit the question, and perhaps add the SQL from the comments above?

Answer (score 2):

Use `lead()` and `lag()` to get the next and previous values.  Then check the timing between them for filtering:

```
select t.amount, t.trans_date
from (select t.*, lead(trans_date) over (order by trans_date) as next_td,
             lag(trans_date) over (order by trans_date) as prev_td
      from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS t
     ) t
where datediff(second, prev_td, trans_date) < 24*60*60 or
      datediff(second, trans_date, next_trans_date) < 24*60*60;
```

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you can do this using `outer apply`:

```
select t.amount, t.trans_date
from (select t.*, tlead.trans_date as next_td,
             tlag.trans_date as prev_td
      from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS t outer apply
           (select top 1 t2.*
            from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS t2
            where t2.trans_date < t.trans_date
            order by trans_date desc
           ) tlag outer apply
           (select top 1 t2.*
            from FIN_AP_PAYMENTS t2
            where t2.trans_date > t.trans_date
            order by trans_date asc
           ) tlead         
     ) t
where datediff(second, prev_td, trans_date) < 24*60*60 or
      datediff(second, trans_date, next_trans_date) < 24*60*60;
```

Comment: MS SQL 2012 + support lead() and lag()

Comment: i am using 2008 r2

Comment: @skzac: "*SQL"* (the query language) **does** support `lead()` and `lag()`. Window functions where introduced to the SQL standard in 2003. That is nothing specific to Oracle

Comment: i am not here to discuss why the functions are not supported in my sql 2008 r2 or when MS launched these functions,

Comment: @skzac: Me neither. But your claim that "*SQL does not support lead or lag*" is simply wrong. (plus: even in Oracle those aren't "PL/SQL functions" they are still SQL functions)

Answer (score 0):

Pre SQL Server 2012 you can use a combination of [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) and [self joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177490(v=sql.105).aspx) instead of LEAD and LAG.

**Example**

```
WITH Example AS
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Trans_Date) AS rn,              
            r.*
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (2645, '2011-05-11 20:57:27.000'),
                    (2640, '2011-05-12 00:00:00.000'),
                    (2645, '2011-05-15 18:01:11.000'),
                    (2645, '2011-06-15 18:27:45.000'),
                    (2645, '2011-06-16 17:06:33.000'),
                    (2645, '2011-06-18 15:19:19.000'),
                    (2645, '2011-06-23 15:42:18.000')
            ) AS r(Amount, Trans_Date)
    )
SELECT
    curr.*,
FROM
    Example AS curr
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Example AS prv      ON prv.rn = curr.rn - 1
        INNER JOIN Example AS nxt           ON nxt.rn = curr.rn + 1
WHERE       
    DATEDIFF(DAY, curr.Trans_Date, nxt.Trans_Date) IN (0, 1)
    OR DATEDIFF(DAY, prv.Trans_Date, curr.Trans_Date) IN (0, 1)
;
```

The [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx) allows you to reuse the row number multiple times.  The row number provides a sequence for the self joins.  The joins allow to you see the previous and next values on the same row, for comparison.

The output of this query doesn't match your example, see my question in the comments for more on this.

I'm not sure that telling people, who are giving up their time to help you, what you are / are not here to discuss is a good idea.  It certainly made me think twice before posting.

Comment: @detination-data : I am aware that people have precious time of their own and just the point is what i asked and what are you saying.. that's it. thanks for the answer anyway.